# Is automating mutex like this in C++ safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

I'm learning about mutex and threading right now. I was wondering if there's anything dangerous or inherently wrong with automating mutex with a class like this:

```
class AutoMutex
{
private:
    std::mutex& m_Mutex;

public:
    AutoMutex(std::mutex& m) : m_Mutex(m)
    {
        m_Mutex.lock();
    }
    ~AutoMutex()
    {
        m_Mutex.unlock();
    }
};
```

And then, of course, you would use it like this:

```
void SomeThreadedFunc()
{
    AutoMutex m(Mutex); // With 'Mutex' being some global mutex.
    // Do stuff
}
```

The idea is that, on construction of an `AutoMutex` object, it locks the mutex. Then, when it goes out of scope, the destructor automatically unlocks it.

You could even just put it in scopes if you don't need it for an entire function. Like this:

```
void SomeFunc()
{
    // Do stuff
    {
        AutoMutex m(Mutex);
        // Do race condition stuff.
    }
    // Do other stuff
}
```

Is this okay? I don't personally see anything wrong with it, but as I'm not the most experienced, I feel there's something I may be missing.

Comment: Works fine. You might want to take a look at [std::scoped_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock)

Comment: std::scoped_lock, std::unique_lock, std::lock_guard with their differences are pretty useful

Comment: Thanks for all of the quick responses! There has been an answer that seems to solve my problem. Although, it may benefit to add std::unique_lock and std::scoped_lock in that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's safe to use a RAII wrapper, and in fact safer than using mutex member functions directly, but it's also unnecessary to write since standard library already provides this. It's called `std::lock_guard`.

However, your implementation isn't entirely safe, because it's copyable, and a copy will attempt to re-unlock the mutex which will lead to undefined behaviour. `std::lock_guard` resolves this issue by being non-copyable.

There's also `std::unique_lock` which is very similar, but allows things such as releasing the lock within the lifetime. `std::scoped_lock` should be used if you need to lock multiple mutexes. Using multiple lock guard may lead to deadlock. `std::scoped_lock` is also fine to use with a single mutex, so you can replace all uses of lock guard with it.

Comment: Sweet! I guess I must be an impatient learner since I'm sure this was coming soon in curriculum. Thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: As some of the other comments have mentioned, there are also std::scoped_lock and std::unique_lock. It might benefit other learners to mention these in your answer.

Comment: "*It's safe*" - only if you don't try to make copies of `AutoMutex`, since it is not following the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) properly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point. I've expanded the answer.